# How do I avoid blurry images with PDF renders of RDLs, especially in Acrobat Reader?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation, acrobat

My team has a consistent issue with blurry images in RDLs rendered as PDFs (such as obvious pixelation at the edges of round images, indistinct text). These issues are most common when viewing the PDF in Acrobat Reader. Many of them resolve when viewing the PDF in a web browser or when at ~200% zoom in Acrobat Reader. Our clients often consume the reports using Acrobat Reader and the reports look unpolished because of the blurry images.

Image:

- Uncompressed pngs
- 600dpi
- Colored (not transparent) backgrounds

RDL settings:

- Sizing: Fit
- Size: In inches at specification from graphic designer
- Source: External

Our best mitigation technique is to place the image inside a rectangle of the same background color as the image background (such as an explicit white background for a round image with a white background).

Are there any other things I can try to improve image quality?

Comment: I've noticed that BMP images show up better in PDFs that JPGs or PNGs. The Sizing to FIT rather than CLIP isn't helping - can you resize the image to match what you need in the report?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The images come to me much larger than they actually need to be, so "clip" or "auto size" gives me an enormous image. I'll follow up with our graphic designer about testing with true-to-size images and bmps.